# How can I find this sum?

Tags: summation, convolution

I'm doing some examples related to convolution (digital signal processing). I post my problem here because it is actually mathematics problem.

I have to calculate this sum:

$$\sum_{k\ = \ n-5}^{n+5} e^{-|k|}$$

Any suggestion?

Comment: It depends on $n$: there are two distinct cases depending on $|n|>5$ or $|n| \le 5$

Comment: Hint: Geometric series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We show the following is valid:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{-|k|}=
> \begin{cases}
> {\displaystyle \frac{e^{-5}-e^{6}}{1-e}e^{-n}}&\qquad\qquad |n|>5\\
> \\
> {\displaystyle \frac{e^{-n-5}-e^{n-5}-1-e}{1-e}}&\qquad\qquad |n|\leq 5
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

Since 
\begin{align*}
e^{-|k|}=
\begin{cases}
e^{-k}&\qquad k\geq 0\\
e^k&\qquad k<0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

we distinguish  *three* different cases:

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{-|k|}=
> \begin{cases}
> {\displaystyle\sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{k}}&\qquad n<- 5\qquad \qquad\text{(i)}\\
> {\displaystyle\sum_{k=n-5}^{-1}e^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n+5}e^{-k}}&\qquad -5\leq n\leq 5\qquad \text{(ii)}\\
> {\displaystyle\sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{-k}}&\qquad n> 5\ \ \qquad \qquad\text{(iii)}\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> Note that cases (i)  and (iii) coincide, since substituting $k$ with $-k$ and changing the order of summation in (iii) gives
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{-k}=\sum_{-k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{k}=\sum_{k=-n-5}^{-n+5}e^{k}
> \end{align*}
>   which is the same as (i) when $n$ is replaced is with $-n$.

We recall the formula of *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* and do some index transformation
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^mq^k&=\frac{1-q^{m+1}}{1-q}\\
\sum_{k=a}^bq^k&=\sum_{k=0}^{b-a}q^{k+a}
=q^a \sum_{k=0}^{b-a}q^{k}\\
&=q^a\frac{1-q^{b-a+1}}{1-q}
\end{align*}

> Now we are well prepared to calculate the cases (i) - (iii)
>
> *Case (i):* $n<-5$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{-|k|}&=\sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{k}\\
> &=\frac{1-e^{[n+5-(n-5)+1]}}{1-e^{-1}}e^{n-5}\\
> &=\frac{1-e^{11}}{1-e}e^{n-5}\\
> &=\frac{e^{-5}-e^{6}}{1-e}e^{n}\\
> \end{align*}
>   *Case (ii):* $-5\leq n\leq 5$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{-|k|}&=\sum_{k=n-5}^{-1}e^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n+5}e^{-k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{-n+4}e^{k+n-5}+\frac{1-e^{-[(n+5)+1]}}{1-e^{-1}}\\
> &=e^{n-5}\frac{1-e^{[(-n+4)+1]}}{1-e}+\frac{1-e^{-n-6}}{1-e^{-1}}\\
> &=e^{n-5}\frac{1-e^{-n+5}}{1-e}+\frac{1-e^{-n-6}}{1-e^{-1}}\\
> &=\frac{e^{-n-5}-e^{n-5}-1-e}{1-e}
> \end{align*}
>   *Case (iii):* $n>5$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{-|k|}&=\sum_{k=n-5}^{n+5}e^{-k}\\
> &=\frac{1-e^{-[n+5-(n-5)+1]}}{1-e^{-1}}e^{-(n-5)}\\
> &=\frac{1-e^{-11}}{1-e^{-1}}e^{-n+5}\\
> &=\frac{e^5-e^{-6}}{1-e^{-1}}e^{-n}\\
> &=\frac{e^{-5}-e^{6}}{1-e}e^{-n}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.